# Disable auto sync for my FTP website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, ftp

I am working with a FTP website on Visual Studio 2013.

Now When ever i change something in any file of that website or just wait 1 minute visual studio automatically try to retrive the file from my ftp server and a message box popup saying. "This file has been modified outside of the source editor. Do you want to reload it?".

Now it's very annoying cause what ever i do i get this message again and again (5 to 6 seconds interval).

I understand that i have change the file and modify the code. Why visual studio ask me to reload it again and again.?

Is their any option which i can disable to stop this auto reload option for FTP sites. Thank you.

If i am not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you are working on a html/css/javaScript file in a FTP server.

If that is the case then why don't you download the file, edit and then upload it again?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I know that. But i open ftp website on visual studio from File->Open Website-> FTP  so your answer is not supported.